# Linux on old hppa c3000, dvd ide found..but not avaliable

Tags: linux, dvd, ide

I run Debian SID on HPPA C3000, a very old workstation from HP.
I have this problem, the ide cd-drom drive seems to be recognized, but no device created.
The dvd is recognized:

```
dmesg |grep -i dvd
[   34.066904] ata1.00: ATAPI: ATAPI   DVD+RW 4X4X12, B1GY, max UDMA/33
```

but no device is created!

```
cdrecord -scanbus
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.

lsblk 
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                         8:0    0 33.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   47M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0  238M  0 part /boot
├─sda3                      8:3    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5                      8:5    0 33.6G  0 part 
  ├─virtualehp--vg-root   254:0    0 19.3G  0 lvm  /
  ├─virtualehp--vg-swap_1 254:1    0  7.6G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─virtualehp--vg-home   254:2    0 26.7G  0 lvm  /home
sdb                         8:16   0 33.9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1                      8:17   0 33.9G  0 part 
  ├─virtualehp--vg-root   254:0    0 19.3G  0 lvm  /
  └─virtualehp--vg-home   254:2    0 26.7G  0 lvm  /home
```

I try to modbprobe pata_legacy and machine go to kernel panic.

edit1: checking dmesg I see errors..

```
[   33.796107] ata1.01: NODEV after polling detection
[   34.013598] ata1.00: ATAPI: ATAPI   DVD+RW 4X4X12, B1GY, max UDMA/33
[   34.406471] ata1.00: TEST_UNIT_READY failed (err_mask=0x2)
[   39.052104] ata1.01: NODEV after polling detection
[   39.056528] ata1.00: NODEV after polling detection
[   39.056554] ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)
[   44.428058] ata1.01: NODEV after polling detection
[   44.432542] ata1.00: NODEV after polling detection
[   44.432569] ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)
[   44.491070] ata1.00: disabled
```

is my unit failed?

Comment: Some CDs need an actual disk inserted before the OS could detect them. Is there a CD disk (not music) inside your CD drive?

Comment: Thansk for reply, was only jumper set to "cable select"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found.
The c3000 manual (which refer to HPUX mainly, not Linux)
report to set "cable select" for cd-rom ide.
But if I set to cable-select report the error on first post
and don't work.
I set it as master and..

```
dmesg |grep -i ata
[    0.000000] Memory: 728K/8388608K available (13700K kernel code, 5256K rwdata, 1893K rodata, 2048K init, 984K bss, 212324K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[   29.712572] Write protected read-only-after-init data: 116k
[   32.558034] libata alternatives: applied 3 out of 3 patches
[   33.122243] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[   33.129506] pata_ns87415 alternatives: applied 1 out of 1 patches
[   33.306191] pata_ns87415 0000:00:0e.0: version 0.0.1
[   33.316422] scsi host0: pata_ns87415
[   33.449893] scsi host1: pata_ns87415
[   33.496606] ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0xf00 ctl 0xe00 bmdma 0xa00 irq 7
[   33.575968] ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0xd00 ctl 0xb00 bmdma 0xa08 irq 7
[   33.832593] ata1.01: NODEV after polling detection
[   33.841220] ata1.00: ATAPI: ATAPI   DVD+RW 4X4X12, B1GY, max UDMA/33
[   39.050358] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ATAPI    DVD+RW 4X4X12    B1GY PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   49.018426] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[   80.547073] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.

ls /dev/sr0 
/dev/sr0
```

cd-info and lsblk report the drive.
So solution found.